# StringTokenizer not Working with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

I am trying to use StringTokenizer with BufferedReader but I am getting an error. 
    It works when I use Scanner but when I change to BufferedReader I can't make it work. I need your input as to what is wrong with my code. This is how my source file looks like:

```
Stud Qu1 Qu2 Qu3 Qu4 Qu5 
1234 052 007 100 078 034 
2134 090 036 090 077 030 
3124 100 045 020 090 070 
4532 011 017 081 032 077 
5678 020 012 045 078 034 
6134 034 080 055 078 045 
7874 060 100 056 078 078 
8026 070 010 066 078 056 
9893 034 009 077 078 020 
1947 045 040 088 078 055 
2877 055 050 099 078 080 
3189 022 070 100 078 077 
4602 089 050 091 078 060 
5405 011 011 000 078 010 
6999 000 098 089 078 020 

And this is the error I am getting:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lab4.Student.<init>(Student.java:26)
    at StudentReportApp.main(StudentReportApp.java:6)

import lab4.*;

public class StudentReportApp {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        String fileName = "input.txt";
        Student studentData = new Student(fileName);
        //studentData.findReport ();
        //studentData.printReport ();
    }
}

public Student (String FileName){
        File file = new File(FileName);

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
            String line;

            br.readLine(); //skips first line
            int r = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
                StringTokenizer stToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                while(stToken.hasMoreTokens()){
                    student[r] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());
                    for (int c = 1; c < 6; c++)
                        grade [r][c-1] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());      
                    r++;
                }
                arrayStudents++;
            }

            student = new int [arrayStudents];
            grade = new int[arrayStudents][5];

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't find file " + file.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file " + file.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: on which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: if you are just splitting my spaces..you can try this too :                
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

Comment: Which line is 28 in Student. java?

Comment: Can you mention the line: since the line numbers are not visible here

Comment: looks like `student[r]` isn't initialized properly. Did u called `student = new Studdent[<int>]();` before?

Comment: student[r] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());

Comment: Student studentData = new Student(fileName);

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your integer arrays so that value can be assigned to its individual elements

```
int[] student = new int[100];
int[][] grade = new int[100][100];
```

(That said, arrays are fixed size, consider using a more flexible collection such as an `ArrayList`)

Answer (score 1):

```
grade [r][c-1] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());
```

in this piece of code you are trying to access the nextToken again..this will move the tokenizer one step ahead of its current position.

Instead you should do first check if that token is available and then access the token.

Correct Way :

```
if(stToken.hasNextToken())
{
 grade[r][c-1] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see

```
br.readLine(); //skips first line
int r = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
    StringTokenizer stToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    while(stToken.hasMoreTokens()){
        student[r] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());
        for (int c = 1; c < 6; c++)
            grade [r][c-1] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());
        r++;
    }
    arrayStudents++;
}

student = new int [arrayStudents];
grade = new int[arrayStudents][5];
```

You first put data inside `grande` and `stutent` then you initalize arrays.

```
student = new int [arrayStudents];
grade = new int[arrayStudents][5];
```

Should go before any use of it. So it will be

```
student = new int [arrayStudents];
grade = new int[arrayStudents][5];

br.readLine(); //skips first line
int r = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
    StringTokenizer stToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    while(stToken.hasMoreTokens()){
        student[r] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());
        for (int c = 1; c < 6; c++)
            grade [r][c-1] = Integer.parseInt(stToken.nextToken());
        r++;
    }
    arrayStudents++;
}
```

Anyway, you cannot use arrayStudents now because you don't know how much students are going to be added.. You could use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to avoid this problem faster.
You could use a class too to improve the code and keep everything better organized..